# Twitter Digits Web CDN SDK redirecting to insecure CDN URL

Tags: twitter-digits, google-fabric, fabric-digits

We have integrated Twitter Digits on our site using their following CDN SDK link

https://cdn.digits.com/1/sdk.js

Sometimes internally it is redirected to following link.

https://cdn-o.digits.com/1/sdk.js

Since this URL is **ENSECURE** I get following error, so the Digits is not defined.

`GET https://cdn-o.digits.com/1/sdk.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

Seems the issue with digits CDN.

or is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because of **WordPress HTTPS** plugin.

We uninstalled it and everything started working normal.